# Changing the enumeration of the sub-figures

Tags: subfloats

I am working on my thesis. There is this rule for the enumeration of the sub-figures:

*Sub-figures should be enumerated by adding the corresponding lowercase letter
to the Figure designation such as Figure 3.8a*

However, I could only manage the 3.8(a)

The code that I am using this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2016.png}
\label{2016}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2017.png}
\label{2017}}
\caption{Graphs of daily averages of Turkish hourly electricity consumption values in \subref{2016} 2016
\subref{2017} 2017.}
\label{consumptions}
\end{figure}
```

The thesis rules tell us to use subfigure package. How can I get 3.8a instead of 3.8(a)? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome t TeX.SE! Please provide complete small document with your figures. Off-topic: it seems that you use obsolete package `subfigure`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by @Zarko in the comments, [subfigure](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is deprecated and is now covered by [subfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption).

To achieve what you want with `subcaption` we'll change the default setup by adding :

```
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption} %%default is [labelformat=parens]

%%Setup for captions
%%If you want figure numbering as 'figure 3.8'
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
%%if you want 3.8a for subfigure
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\normalsize\thefigure.\alph{subfigure}:}
%%if you want figure 3.8a for subfigure
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\normalsize figure \thefigure.\alph{subfigure}:}
```

Here is a complete testing code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption} %%default is [labelformat=parens]
%%If you want figure numbering as 'figure 3.8'
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
%%if you want 3.8a
%\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\normalsize\thefigure.\alph{subfigure}:}
%%if you want figure 3.8a
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\normalsize figure \thefigure.\alph{subfigure}:}



\begin{document}
    \chapter{fist chapter}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{Test}
        \end{subfigure}\hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
            \caption{Test}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Total}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Who produces the following output :

[image: Output]